# Why does the “no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash” error occur in Trailblazer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, trailblazer

I ran into one problem that I cannot solve on my own for a week - I am desperate.

I got a Rails 5.2 project that has a Trailblazer on board. In one place of the application, I catch this error:

```
TypeError - no implicit conversion of Symbol into Hash:
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/_authors_tab.slim:10:in `block (2 levels) in singleton class'
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/_authors_tab.slim:9:in `block in singleton class'
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/_authors_tab.slim:65534:in `singleton class'
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/_authors_tab.slim:65531:in `__tilt_70096639860360'
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/show.slim:14:in `block in singleton class'
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/show.slim:65534:in `singleton class'
  app/concepts/post/admin/views/show.slim:65531:in `__tilt_70096639860360'
  app/concepts/post/admin/cell.rb:13:in `show'
  app/views/admin/posts/show.slim:3:in `_app_views_admin_posts_show_slim__1322321696587881215_70096664842560'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:71:in `apply_time_zone'

Started POST "/__better_errors/51d28299c14c669d/variables" for ::1 at 2018-10-22 15:00:18 +0300
```

**_authors_tab.slim:10** (9 and 10 lines):

```
- authors.each do |author|
  = concept 'post/author/list_item/cell', author, context: :admin
```

Below is the code that I specifically cut for the best presentation (the error, of course, was preserved):

```
class Post::Author::ListItem::Cell < RBlog::Cell
  option_property :context, nil_check: true

  def show
    render
  end
end
```

This is a file (**app/concepts/r_blog/cell/option_property.rb**) with a description of an unknown method:

```
module RBlor::Cell::OptionProperty
  def option_property(name, nil_check: false)
    if nil_check
      define_method(name) do
        raise "Option #{name} cannot be blank" if @options[name].nil?
        @options[name]
      end
    else
      define_method(name) { @options[name] }
    end
    private name
  end
end
```

As for the file `show.slim` from the code above - I commented on all its contents, deleted it and even left it intact (with the methods described in`Post :: Author :: ListItem :: Cell`, but which were deleted, as I wrote above ) - this file does not affect anything. Apparently the error appears before it is processed.

What could be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you trying to do in your first line in the cell

`option_property` -> that's not a defined method call anywhere in Cells project if I remember correctly.

P.S.:
I suggest to head down to the Gitter channel for TRB project, you will get a response there much quicker than anywhere else.

Comment: I didn't even think about it. But thanks. I added the code to the text.

Comment: I comment on the contents of the option_property method (that is, define_method returns null) - the error is still saved.

Comment: Another thing that jumps at me is that you passing `:admin` to `context:` which is a a "special"  object within cell, and you are also defining a property/method named ":context" on your cell.  I think you have a name conflict there . See this https://github.com/trailblazer/cells/blob/2d33ad03a7c973123ca40be7eb8a85ad9f859550/CHANGES.md#410

Comment: Here is a more direct link: https://github.com/trailblazer/cells/blob/2d33ad03a7c973123ca40be7eb8a85ad9f859550/CHANGES.md#awesomeness

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `context: :i_am_a_symbol`, that option is expecting a Hash and not a symbol!